# Best way to visualize a house floor plan with satellite imagery?

Tags: floor-plan, home-automation

I have a few acres of land of where I want to build a house. I am currently deciding between floor plans and was wondering if it's possible to superimpose floor plans to scale on satellite imagery so I can determine the best angle to position a house on the land. I am thinking that scaling a floorplan over google earth imagery using Google Earth Pro would be an idea...but is there something better/easier out there and free?

Comment: This will be more difficult to do unless the land is relatively flat. is it?

Comment: Lo-tech? print out a screen dump of Google earth, cut out a rectangle to represent your house & play around until happy?

Comment: I just may do that!

Comment: And, did you? :-) Or did you find another solution? Your answer could help others

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen this ? https://www.scribblemaps.com/   it is an online that you can draw around the land of the house and export it to Google Earth Pro.

Answer (score 0):

Most if not all of the 2D planning and CAD systems will allow you to put a background image in. The trick is getting it to match the scale of the drawing.

[Sketchup](http://www.sketchup.com/) would work as well.

This shouldn't be that hard assuming you know the dimensions of some visible features. You can simply scale the image to match.

In fact using Google images alone is not necessarily a good idea without scaling them manually because Google use a flat plan projection which is typically a metre or 2 out.